# How can I remove and keep the elements of this set?

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

I have a list

```
list = {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}, {6, 2, 7, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7}, {2, 8, 8, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6}, {5, 7, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4}, {8, 10, 10, 8, 2, 1, 2, 4}}
```

Consider an element of list, with two item `i` and `i+1`. If all the pair `(i, i+1)` (`i` stand at odd position from left to right) so that `GCD[i, i+1]==1`, we keef this element. If there is a pair `(i, i+1)` so that `GCD[i, i+1]` different 1, then we remove that element.

With this rule, the list only keep the element `{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}` How can I tell *Mathematica* to do that? I do not how to start.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

According to the comment, we should divide the 8 element to 4 pairs.

```
Select[list, And @@ (GCD @@@ Partition[#, 2] == 1 // Thread) &]
```

**Original**

```
Select[list, And @@ (GCD @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] == 1 // Thread) &]
```

> `{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}`.

Comment: `list = {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}, {6, 2, 7, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7}, {2, 8, 8, 2, 3, 
  2, 4, 6}, {5, 7, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4}, {8, 10, 10, 8, 2, 1, 2, 4}, {4, 
  1, 7, 10, 5, 4, 6, 7}` with that list, the element `{4, 1, 7, 10, 5, 4, 6, 7}` does not remove.

Comment: I think 
`Select[list, And @@ (GCD @@@ Partition[#, 2] == 1 // Thread) &]` is correct.

Answer (score 6):

```
f1 = BlockMap[If[CoprimeQ @@ #, Splice @ #, Nothing] &, #, 2] &; 

f1 /@ list
```

> ```
>  {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7},  
>   {7, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7},  
>   {3, 2},  
>   {5, 7, 7, 5, 2, 1},  
>   {2, 1}}
> ```

Also

```
f2 = Flatten @ Select[Apply @ CoprimeQ] @ Partition[#, 2] &;

f2 /@ list
```

> same result

**Update:** If you need to find the members of `list` that does not lose any elements under your selection rule, you can use `f1` and `f2`

```
Select[ f1 @ # == # &] @ list
```

> ```
>  {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}}
> ```

```
Select[ f2 @ # == # &] @ list
```

> ```
>  {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}}
> ```

Alternatively, more directly

```
s1 = Select[And @@ BlockMap[Apply[CoprimeQ], #, 2] &];


s2 = Select[Apply[And]@MapApply[CoprimeQ]@Partition[#, 2] &];
```

An using (still-undocumented) 6-argument form of `Partition` as follows:

```
s3 = Select[And @@ Partition[#, 2, 2, 1, {}, CoprimeQ] &];
```

All three methods give the same result

```
# @ list & /@ {s1, s2, s3}
```

> ```
>  {{{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}},  
>   {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}},   
>   {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Using `//.` is also interesting.

> If all the pair (i, i+1) (I stand at the odd position from left to right) so that GCD[i, i+1]==1, we keep this element.

```
keepQ = (# //. {x_,y_,z___} /; GCD[x,y] === 1 :> {z} // EqualTo[{}]) &
```

so

```
Select[keepQ][list]
```

> {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}}

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `Pick`, `Partition` and `AllTrue`:

```
list1 = {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}, {6, 2, 7, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7}, 
         {2, 8, 8,2, 3, 2, 4, 6}, {5, 7, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4},
         {8, 10, 10, 8, 2, 1, 2, 4}};

list2 = {{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}, {6, 2, 7, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7}, 
         {2, 8, 8,2, 3, 2, 4, 6}, {5, 7, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4}, 
         {8, 10, 10, 8, 2, 1, 2, 4}, {4, 1, 7, 10, 5, 4, 6, 7}};

Pick[#, AllTrue[Partition[#, {2}], GCD[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == 1 &] & /@ #] &@list1

(*{{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}}*)

Pick[#, AllTrue[Partition[#, {2}], GCD[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == 1 &] & /@ #] &@list2

(*{{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}, {4, 1, 7, 10, 5, 4, 6, 7}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the lists of E. Chan-López

```
f[x_] /; AllTrue[# == 1 &] @ MapApply[GCD] @ Partition[x, 2] := x
f[_] := Nothing

f /@ list1
```

{{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}}

```
f /@ list2
```

{{1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7}, {4, 1, 7, 10, 5, 4, 6, 7}}